# Remove desktop service Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04

I made an application using Qt for Ubuntu 16.04. I want only my application to run on the system and want to stop all other GUI to be non interactive. On windows I can do that by disabling the explorer.exe.
Is there any similar way to to this in Ubuntu? I could only find to disable the nautilus service.

I tried to disable the GUI interface and opened the application using CLI. My application runs on 2 desktop screens so that doesn't work as well. The resolution is not supported by Ubuntu.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Search for *kiosk mode*

Comment: I open my application on startup and full screen mode by default so it is kind of in kiosk mode. But when any information or error message box pops up from my application the status bar and the launcher are shown.